# JMeter Read CSV file contents into JUnit testcase program using CSV Data Set Config

Tags: variables, junit, jmeter

I add the code:

```
JUnitSampler junitSampler=new JUnitSampler(); 
String UserId=junitSampler.getThreadContext().getVariables().get("username");
```

to Junit code I see an error red squiggly lines in Eclipse at `import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler;`

How to clear the following error:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `ApacheJMeter_junit.jar` in your classpath.

jar includes the `JUnitSampler` class you are missing.

The jar can be found inside `JMETER_HOME\lib\ext` folder

Comment: now getting in error in getThreadContext().getVariables() method 
  my following code looks like                                           
 JUnitSampler junitSampler = new JUnitSampler();
  String UserId = junitSampler.getThreadContext().getVariables().get("foo");  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(UserId);

Comment: SO isn't used for debugging your code. if you have another concrete issue. open a new question with details

Answer (score 0):

Use the following construction:

```
String UserId = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("UserId");
```

The above statement assuming having [ApacheJMeter_core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core) library in your project classpath.

---

Be aware of 2 facts:

1. It would be way easier to use [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) if you plan to integrate Selenium with JMeter
2. If you want to create the main load using multiple instances of Chrome browser - it is better to reconsider the approach before you waste too much time as Chrome is **very** resources intensive and the chance you will be able to run at least 10 instances on a single host is minimal. If you have an existing set of Selenium functional tests and would like to convert them into load tests you can just configure your Selenium tests to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as a [proxy](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) so your Selenium calls would be translated into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which has less footprint in terms of CPU and Memory. See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) for more details if needed